# Eager Load Constraints Filter issue in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, eager-loading

I am unable to filter the contents of `groups` table with respect to `username` in `users` table using [Eager Load Constraints](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading)

```
public function username()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User','fk_users_id')->select(['id','username']);
}
```

I have tried using the code below but it filters only the `users` data not the `groups` data

```
$groups     =   Groups::with(array('username' => function($query) use ($keyword)
                                                        {
                                                            $query->where('username', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%');

                                                        }))
                ->where('status',1)->paginate($paginateValue);
```

any help is welcome...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `array('user' => function($query)`? Or is `username` a table?

Comment: `username` is a function

Answer (score 0):

Think it should be something like this:

```
Groups::with('User')->whereHas('User', function($q) use ($key){
 $q->where('username', 'like', '%'.$key.'%');
})->where('status', 1)->paginate($pagVal);
```